# How to convert BigDecimal to float having 2 decimal in java

Tags: java, java-8, bigdecimal

How can I convert a BigDecimal to float, having 2 decimal in java?

```
BigDecimal x=new BigDecimal(any exponential term);
```

Now I want to convert to float having 2 decimal point only, for example -0.45.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [setScale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-java.math.RoundingMode-) to round number to any given decimal places.

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(2.36359);
float rounded = number.setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN).floatValue();
System.out.println(rounded);    // prints "2.36"
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you have the BigDecimal. Use x.floatValue() to compute float and then pass it through Math.round() to round it to 2 digits.